# Conditional formatting, referencing an image from the 14 hive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have placed a condition format on a column however it will not let me select an image from the 14Hive, only from a place within the site.

I have tried placeing ~/layouts/ etc etc in the baground image property to no avail!

Was wondering if anyone had a solution for this. Yes i could place the images in the site but why duplicate the image as it is already in the 14 hive!

Cheers
    Truez

Answer (score 4):

Try using relative URL starting with forward slash, such as /_layouts/images/image1.gif. Images folder does not have permissions on it, so you can access it from any site with this URL.

Comment: I had already tried /_layouts/images/a.gif but it didn't work.....grrrr! I'm wondering if it's because i am trying to do this via sharepoint designer

Comment: Could be, i've seen SPD doing some nasty replacements